# Using Python SQLite3 to find latin alphabets in column

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a column in sqlite3 table containing all the chemical elements.  There is a column called “Symbol”, where it contains symbols of chemicals. For example, H, Be, Mg.

I would like to pull out all characters from A-Z that does not appear in the column (not case sensitive). Below is what i have currently

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('chemicals.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('select Symbol from chemicalElements')
rows = cur.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(row)
```

Example of table below

| code | Symbol | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | H | Hydrogen |
| 2 | He | Helium |
| 3 | N | Nitrogen |
| 4 | Mg | Magnesium |

In this case, the final output should be alphabets other than H,E,N,M,G

Comment: Hi, which 2 columns are you referring to?

Comment: Can you please try and explain again? It is clear that you have a DB table. Can you share the definition of this table?

Comment: *Coincidentally* this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69955103/apply-sqlite3-library-to-filter-alphabets-from-column is a very similar question posted earlier today.

Comment: I have added a table and output

Comment: @MsY Please share the `CREATE TABLE ` SQL

Comment: All these characters: H,E,N,M,G do appear in the column Symbol!

Comment: Yes, hence my desired output would be all other characters from A-Z instead of H,E,N,M,G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a group concat in your query to get all the symbols in one string, then use a set to hold only the unique letters.
Create a set of the letters of the alphabet and do a symmetric difference operation on them.

```
import string

conn = sqlite3.connect('chemicals.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("select upper(group_concat(symbol,'')) from chemicalElements")
row = cur.fetchone()
symbols = set(row[0])
alphabet = set(string.ascii_uppercase)
other_symbols = alphabet.symmetric_difference(symbols)
print(other_symbols)
```

Answer (score 1):

Build up a set of all the characters you do find, subtract that from the set of all letters.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('chemicals.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('select Symbol from chemicalElements')
rows = cur.fetchall()
found = set()
for row in rows:
    found = found.union(list(row[0].upper()))
missing = set(string.ascii_uppercase) - found
print(missing)
```